# Reflection coefficient of surface with sources

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

While solving the maxwell equation for surface where both surface charge and current density are present to calculate its reflection coefficient, i.e.

$$\nabla \times E=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}B$$

$$\nabla \cdot E=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$$

$$\nabla \times H=J+\frac{\partial}{\partial t} D$$

$$\nabla \cdot B=0$$

How to calculate the reflection coefficient of such surface for both TE and TM mode, I tried using the usual method of homogenous equation, but confused over what to substitute for $J$ and $\rho$ at the interface.

I had gone through some of the standard books but they only discuss about the source free situation. I also refer to some papers with no success.

Atleast if somebody can help me how to deal with surface charge and current density in such scenario, I will very grateful for that

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're interested in reflection at a metal. The easiest way to deal with this problem is to set the sources to 0, and consider only the [boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields) at the interface. The reason you can do this is because in the region you're interested (outside the metal) the charges and currents are 0, so the homogeneous equation is accurate. The boundary conditions take care of any surface currents or charges, because the incoming wave induces currents and surface charges to exactly enforce the boundary conditions.

The two key boundary conditions you need are that the electric field parallel to the metal is 0 at the boundary, and the magnetic field perpendicular to the field at the boundary is 0.

If you're really interested in the effect of sources that are independent of the incoming wave, then you can treat the problem as a superposition of an incoming and reflected wave (with the same solution as previously) together with the outgoing radiation or fields due to the sources. The additional sources don't affect the behaviour of the reflected wave.

Comment: But, what about the cases where the sources are non-zeros especially for plasma sheet, I encountered such cases and try to solve for reflection coefficient by using the usual method of boundary condition. But, I'm not able to understand what needs to be substituted for J and rho. In one of the book Classical electricity and Magnetism by M.Philips, they discuss such situation but I'm not able to understand. For example, J  is  proportional to  $E_{||}$  but how E can substituted in terms of incident or reflected field so that I can calculate the reflection coefficient

Comment: Any specific book you can suggest where such cases has been thoroughly discussed.

Comment: In a lot of cases for plasma physics, you can use expressions for the [dielectric constant](http://physics.usask.ca/~xiaoc/phys463/notes/note12.pdf) of a plasma, which includes the effects of current. Then you can use all the regular expressions for reflection at a dielectric interface. The source I've linked seems like a fairly good introduction to the concepts. Plasma physics can get crazy though, so such a simple model isn't always valid. I can't recommend a book, sorry.